# Apache-Spark: Nested for-comprehensions for RDDs

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, for-comprehension

I am trying to do the Spark-RDD equivalent of this local Scala code:

```
val intList1=List(1,2,3,4,5,6)
val intList2=List(10,20,30,40,50,60)

val divisiblePairs=for(
    int1<-intList1;
    int2<-intList2
    if int2 % int1 == 0
) yield(int1,int2)

divisiblePairs.groupBy(_._1) //Map(6 -> List((6,30), (6,60)),...)
```

I tried:

```
val intRDD1=sc.parallelize(List(1,2,3,4,5,6))
val intRDD2=sc.parallelize(List(10,20,30,40,50,60))

val divisiblePairs=
for(
    int1<-intRDD1;
    int2<-intRDD2
    if int2 % int1 == 0
) yield(int1,int2)
```

which would need some extra work, but I am getting errors, even in the body of the for-comprehension:

> error: type mismatch;  found   :
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Int)]  required: TraversableOnce[?]
>              int2<-intList2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is to be expected because Spark doesn't support nesting. You can use `cartesian` method to do the same thing:

```
for {
  (int1, int2) <- intRDD1.cartesian(intRDD2)
  if int2 % int1 == 0
} yield(int1, int2)
```

Comment: Is it not possible for Spark to internally convert the nested for-comprehension to cartesian products?